# Scribus .eps file export is unsatisfactory

Tags: scribus

In Scribus 1.4.5, I exported my .sla file into the Encapsulated PostScript format:
**File -> Export -> Save as EPS**
Indeed, Scribus created an .eps file.  I verified that the font was embedded (subsetted in this case) by looking inside of it:
**less myfile.eps**
The problem with myfile.eps is that the 500 point font (that's a big size) has jagged edges when viewed in a typical viewing app, such as GwenView.  You don't see the jagged edges until you zoom into the font.  And so here is my question: How do I tell the Scribus EPS export function to create even more resolution within the embedding?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Scribus' main export target is PDF.

All other export formats are there for your comfort (and because once you have the EPS import, the EPS export might be easy to create).

If you're not happy with the result, you should really export a PDF from Scribus and then convert that PDF into whatever your final target is.

Also -- as far as I know -- Scribus' EPS export, is using Ghostscript (GS): if you have some degree of programming literacy, you can have a look at the parameters Scribus is passing to GS and see if there is anything you can do to improve the EPS export.
On the other side, from you description of the problem, I fear a mismatch between the curves Scribus is providing to the exporter and the ones GS can define for EPS... Which would be harder to fix. But it's not easy to say anything without seeing your files and eventually having checked the code involved.

Comment: Eh eh... Doug seem to be comfortable with the idea of exporting to PDF and then convert to EPS. He has said so, in an edit to my post that was rejected by the moderator because it should have been written as a comment... So, here is a comment that says so...